# Is it possible to develop PowerPC applications on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: xcode, macos, powerpc, osx-tiger

I have an iMac g3 running Tiger 10.4.11. I'm really interested in developing applications for it, but I would like to do all of the programming on my Macbook Pro(running Yosemite).

**Is it possible to build an application on Yosemite that will run on PowerPC macs?** I've tried downloading xCode 3.1.4, but it isn't supported on Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine you cannot. Apple stripped PowerPC emulation from it's latest versions of OSX so if you can't run the apps it's only logical to think that you couldn't develop or compile them.

As far as I'm aware the latest version of OSX that can run PPC apps is Snow Leopard, although I cannot comment on Xcode support for developing for PowerPC architectures.

Yosemite as far as I'm aware definitely will not serve as a platform to develop PowerPC apps.

Comment: That's sad:( I'd imagine the only way to program ppc apps "on Yosemite" would be through a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. What you need to do is restore PowerPC support in your version of Xcode like described here: https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy